# Move to next input field on pressing Tab in Flutter Windows Application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield, flutter-windows

I have a form with multiple [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html). I would like for the user to be able to move to the next field using tab or go back using Shift+Tab. The page looks as follows:

[image]

When I focus on Contract Number field and press tab, instead of going to composition field it goes to Invoices written in the Side Navigation which is created using [NavigationRail](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html). And on pressing tab again it moves to Payments. And on third tab it moves to Composition Text Field.

Is there a way I can fix the order in which this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a traversal group. For example if you have 10 elements in a column you can wrap the column and add a policy

```
FocusTraversalGroup(
      policy: OrderedTraversalPolicy()
      child: Column(),
 )
```

More info [focusTraversalGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusTraversalGroup-class.html)